# Range массив и стили

Tags: vba

Задача такая. Имеется столбец в именованной таблице, в ячейках которого текст многостроковый и требуется задать стили подстрокам в тексте.
С обработкой и форматированием ячеек через цикл проблем нет. Интересует, как можно range сохранить как range массив, чтобы затем в цикле каждый элемент можно было с помощью свойства characters форматировать текст и после сохранить обратно в исходный столбец таблицы?

И получится ли некий профит в скорости при форматировании текста в массиве?

Comment: Никак. Такое форматирование производится на листе. Нет, можно, конечно, диапазон присвоить переменной (Set rRng = Range()...), но это не то, что Вам нужно. Возможно, будет чуток быстрее, проверьте.

Comment: Понял, жаль, спасибо) Надеялся сделать пушку гонку из скрипта сделав форматирование через массив, а не через range.